# Translate booking ads to AMP page

Tags: amp-html

I want to translate

```
<ins class="bookingaff" data-aid="1278405" data-target_aid="1278405" 
data-prod="nsb" data-width="300" data-height="250" data-lang="es" data- 
df_num_properties="3">
<!-- Anything inside will go away once widget is loaded. -->
<a href="//www.booking.com?aid=1278405">Booking.com</a>
</ins>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(d, sc, u) {
var s = d.createElement(sc), p = d.getElementsByTagName(sc)[0];
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.async = true;
s.src = u + '?v=' + (+new Date());
p.parentNode.insertBefore(s,p);
})(document, 'script', 
'//aff.bstatic.com/static/affiliate_base/js/flexiproduct.js');
</script>
```

to an AMP Page https://www.ampproject.org/es/ What's the tag? How do you do it? amp-iframe? How? Thanks!!

Comment: You may want to check this [link](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/converting) on how to convert AMP page from an existing HTML page. Also this [page](https://www.cardinaldigitalmarketing.com/blog/converting-to-amp-landing-pages/) discussed how to use AMP landing pages with AdWords

Comment: Thanks @abielita but I have already checked those links. This is a little more advanced